# Data does not display right in table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I'm trying to display data in the table, but for some reasons appears empty fields. I think the issue is that firstly is looking deaths - fills the  elements and cases becomes empty. Tried to do in many different ways. In some ways all data are just pulled in one column, in other ways the data just go in rows. Tryied to use lodash as well.
Current code:

```
 <table className="table">
          <tr>
            <th>Cases</th>
            <th>Deaths</th>
          </tr>
          {_.map(countryData, (item, key) => {
            if (item.indicator === "cases") {
              return (
                <tr>
                  <td>{item.weekly_count}</td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
              );
            } else {
              return (
                <tr>
                  <td>{item.weekly_count}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            }
          })}
        </table>
```

Also tried in this way(still empty fields):

```
 {countryData.map((value, key) => {
            return (
              <tr>
                <td>
                  {value.indicator === "cases" ? value.weekly_count : null}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {value.indicator === "deaths" ? value.weekly_count : null}
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
```

My data from console.log:
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldkwt.png)

Expected result: [expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a44gD.jpg)

Example of issue: [Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVVm5.png)

countryData: [This data comes after selecting the specific country](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGA4X.png)

Comment: Hi. Can you share what does countryData object look like? If possible, try sharing the codesandbox.

Comment: countryData is array of objects. If you need an example of it let me know. https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-lewin-f0teu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: The response.data obtained from "/api" does not form an array. Please make sure that "data" varaiable stores an array.

Comment: Check the countryData image, attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map function is working just fine. The problem is with the object `countryData`. The object currently does not contain an array. Please make sure the object looks like:

`countryData = [{indicator:"cases", weekly_count: xx}, {indicator:"deaths", weekly_count: yy}.....]`

I have only used two fields inside each object, you may add more objects according to your requirement.

In order to view cases and deaths as separate columns, please add an empty cell before displaying "deaths".

```
{_.map(countryData, (item, key) => {
            if (item.indicator === "cases") {
              return (
                <tr>
                  <td>{item.weekly_count}</td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
              );
            } else {
              return (
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>{item.weekly_count}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            }
          })}
```

Comment: As you see from the last image('countryData') the whole data is displayed like countryData = [{},{},{}]. Is that wrong?

Comment: The image shows the data being displayed in the back-end app right? When you make an API call using axios, try and find out the response you get by doing a console.log(). I can;t do that on codesandbox since i don't have the access to your back-end. I tried running the code with a custom "data" object and the code runs fine.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-platform-qwu8l?file=/src/App.js Have a look here...

Comment: The image displays data from axios call. I can actually manipulate the date in front-end now. The whole issue is that I can't put the data in 2 different columns. Because the objects goes like deaths deaths deaths cases cases cases and etc... So firstly fills up deaths and then leaves empty cases, after that starts filling up cases and leaves empty spaces at deaths. I want them to go row by row without any empty spaces

Comment: The death number should be in death column.

Comment: Edited the answer. Please try the suggested code. Here is the codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-platform-qwu8l?file=/src/App.js .

Comment: They are still not in a one row :)

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do here. Try to post an example of countryData here. I want to know if all the objects are gonna have a cases AND deaths fields, or only one of these.

Comment: Solved. I took all deaths/cases to 2 different arrays. And looped through these ones and printed output.

Comment: Yes, that would be the approach to display them independent of each other. If you are storing both of them in the same array, you can only display either of them in one row. Anyway, thanks for accepting the answer.